# AuthorizeAttribute on BaseController HttpContext.User.Identity.Name in policy missing

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, authorize-attribute, asp.net-authorization

In my asp.net core Web API i want to be sure that Users actually exist and are not deactivated when calling some Actions. We use JwtBearer authentication what works pretty fine. Our problem is that using only the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizeAttribute` it won't matter, if a user was deleted or deactivated after the token was issued (as long as the token it self is valid).

In my `Startup.cs` i configured a policy to solve this issue:

```
     services.AddAuthentication(options =>
       {
           options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
       }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
       {
           options.TokenValidationParameters = AuthenticationHandler.TokenValidationParameters;
       });
       services.AddAuthorization(options =>
       {
           options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
                                     JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
               .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
               .Build();
           options.AddPolicy(nameof(ExistingUserRequirement), 
                   policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new ExistingUserRequirement()));
       });
       services.AddTransient<IAuthorizationHandler, ExistingUserHandler>();
```

There i query the DataContext if the user is existing and active.
What works:
If I configure the `Authorization` attribute on an action everything works fine:

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize(Policy = nameof(ExistingUserRequirement))]
public JsonResult Post([FromBody]CreateStoryViewModel viewModel) { ...}
```

I can access the requests user identity using `HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`.

**What not works:** If I configure the attribute on my `BaseController` the Identity-context seems the be missing when the `ExistingUserHandler` fires up:

```
[Authorize(Policy = nameof(ExistingUserRequirement))]
public abstract class BaseController : Controller { ... }
```

Now Identity.Name returns always `NULL`:

```
public class ExistingUserHandler : AuthorizationHandler<ExistingUserRequirement>
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor { get; }

    private SaycleContext SaycleContext { get; }

    public ExistingUserHandler(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor, SaycleContext saycleContext)
    {
        HttpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
        SaycleContext = saycleContext;
    }

    protected override Task HandleRequirementAsync(AuthorizationHandlerContext authorizationContext, ExistingUserRequirement requirement)
    {
        var exists = false;
        if (Guid.TryParse(HttpContextAccessor.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name, out var currentUserId))
        {
            exists = SaycleContext.Users.Any(u => Equals(u.Id, currentUserId));
        }
        if (!exists)
        {
            throw new NonExistingUserException();
        }
        authorizationContext.Succeed(requirement);
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Am I missing anything? Why can the identity-context not be resolved using the `Authorize` attribute on my parent `BaseController`?